# How to derive $F^{\mu\nu}$ from $F_{\mu\nu}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Let $\vec  A = [\phi, A_x, A_y, A_z]$ be a vector field, and a covariant tensor field be defined as

$$ F_{ab} = \frac{\partial A_a}{\partial x_b} -  \frac{\partial A_b}{\partial x_a}$$

Can the contravariant tensor field $F^{ab}$ be computed by calculating the 4x4 matrix inverse at each point?

Comment: $F^{ab}$ is not the inverse of $F_{a,b}$ but rather the sum $F_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\mu a}\eta^{\nu b}$. You’re raising the indices of a covariant tensor with the metric to obtain a contra variant tensor.

Comment: I’ll add more about this in a bit in a full answer, but really this makes the most when we think of everything in terms of differential forms.

Comment: @Chris thank you. it would be great if you could also please help explain what $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ signifies, and why does this expression occur in the Lagrangian?

Comment: Could you provide more detail on the context from where your question arises? In particular, what is the space on which $F$ and $A$ are tensors?

Comment: @Deane They're not using a flat connection, they're implicitly using an abelian structure group for the principal bundle on which their connection lives. Hence, since locally $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\nu A_\mu-\partial_\mu A_\mu+[A_\mu,A_\nu]$, the lie bracket drops out. I'm pretty sure this is an electromagnetism problem, hence $P=\mathbb{R}^{1,3}\times U(1)$.

Comment: @Chris, thanks. You're correct. I didn't look at this carefully enough.

Comment: @Deane do you think my post answers the question? Im worried it introduced too much too quickly

Comment: To be honest, there's too little context provided in the question for me to know how to answer it. Your answer is a little long but it does seem correct to me.

Comment: @Chris thank you vm. Deane, the context is electromagnetism. Maxwell's equations can be fully specified using a single 4 component vector field $[\phi, A_x, A_y,  A_z]$ and operations on this vector field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I am going to denote my coordinate frame for vector fields by $\partial_i$. So your vector field $A$ can be written as:

$$A=\phi\partial_t +A_x\partial_x+A_y\partial_y +A_z\partial_z$$

A one form is a $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{1,3})$ linear functional on vector fields, (I'll denote the space of vector fields by $\mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^{1,3})$, that is a map:
$$\omega:\mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^{1,3})\rightarrow C^\infty(M)$$
such that for any vector field's $X,Y$, and any smooth functions $f,g$, we have that:
$$\omega(gX+fY)=g\omega(X)+f\omega(Y)$$
It is not hard to see that the set of all one forms is a $\mathbb{R}$-linear vector space, and that it is a $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{1,3})$ module. Given this, we have a coordinate coframe $dx^i$ which satisfies:
$$dx^i(\partial_j)=\delta^i_j$$
We can make $k$ forms out $1$-forms by use of the wedge product, which is a product that satisfies:
$$dx^i\wedge dx^j=-dx^j\wedge dx^i$$
Note that this implies that $dx^i\wedge dx^i=0$. We also have a map from $k$ forms to $k+1$ given by the exterior derivative $d$. It is given on $0$ forms (smooth functions) by:
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}dx^i$$
where the Einstein summation convention is implies. On one forms it is given by:
$$d(f_idx^i)=\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x^j}dx^i\wedge dx^j$$
on two forms by:
$$d(f_{ij}dx^i\wedge dx^j)=\frac{\partial f_{ij}}{\partial x^k}dx^k\wedge 
dx^i\wedge dx^j$$
It is not too difficult to see that $d(d(\omega))=0$ for al $k$ forms.

Ok, but what does all of this have to do with your contravariant vs. covariant tensor? Well, differential forms are covariant tensors (specifically antisymmetric covariant tensors), and vector fields, and their tensor products are contravariant tensors. I'm assuming that this is for a course in electromagnetism, so there is also another type of symmetric, covariant tensor on your spacetime $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$, in particular it is the inner product $\eta$ which is given on Minkowski space time by:
$$\eta=-dt\otimes dt+\delta_{ij}dx^i\otimes dx^j$$
The inner product is non degenerate, so in particular it as an inverse:
$$\eta^{-1}=-\partial_t\otimes \partial_t+\delta_{ij}\partial_i\otimes \partial_j$$
by which I mean if we think about these objects as matrices, their product satisfies:
$$\eta_{ij}\eta^{jk}=\delta_i^k$$
where $\eta^{jk}$ are the components of the inverse metric i.e. $\eta(\eta^{-1})=\text{Id}$.

Now $\eta$ is a bilinear map $\mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^{1,3})\times \mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^{1,3})\rightarrow C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{1,3})$. Given this, if we have vector field $X$, we can easily define a one form $\omega$ by:
$$\omega(Y)=\eta(X,Y)$$
In coordinate, this amounts to the one form:
$$X\lrcorner \eta=dt(X)dt+\delta_{ij}dx^i(X)dx^j$$
If $X=X^i\partial_i$ we have that:
$$X\lrcorner \eta=X^i\eta_{ij}dx^j$$
if we set $X_j=X^i\eta_{ij}$ then we can rewrite this as:
$$X\lrcorner \eta=X_jdx^j$$
This is the process of lowering indices, and we can do something similar for differential forms, i.e. given a one form form $\omega=F_idx^i$, we can use the inver metric to get a vector field $\omega\lrcorner \eta^{-1}=F_i \eta^{ij}\partial_j=F^j\partial_j$. This is called raising indices, and both of these operations are isomorphisms from the space of vector fields to the space of $1$ forms. Analogously for $2$ forms, we can find antisymmetric products of vector fields by:

$$\omega\lrcorner\eta^{-1}=\omega_{ij}\eta^{ik}\eta^{jl}\partial_i\wedge \partial_j$$

Ok so now let's get back to the question at hand. We start with four potential which is a vector field as defined above. We then take $A$ to a one form with metric to obtain the following one form:

$$A=-\phi dt+A_idx^i$$
where the $A_i$ functions were unchanged because the components of the metric on those basis vectors are $1$. We then take the exterior derivative to obtain the curvature two form:
$$F=dA=\left(\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x^j}-\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x^i}\right) dx^i\wedge dx^j$$
the components of $F$ are precisely your $F_{ab}$. You can then raise the indices to obtain a wedge product of vector fields.

I can't fully explain the reason $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ pops up in the Lagrangian without going into detail about non abelian gauge theories, but I can provide a heuristic argument in terms of  Electromagnetism. First, the metric $\eta$ induces a metric on the space of differential $k$ forms, given by:
$$\langle \omega,\omega\rangle=\frac{1}{k!}\omega_{i_1\cdots i_k}\omega^{i_1\cdots i_k}$$
So essentially, our action functional is given by this inner product. This is important, as the the inner product is non degenerate, so the $L_2$ inner product is nondegenerate. In particular, we can write the action of a given four potential $A$ by:

$$S[A]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{1,3}} \langle F,F\rangle d^4x$$

We can vary the action with respect to $A$ and we'll get the source free maxwell field equation:
$$d\star F=0$$
where $\star$ is hodge star operator. This, coupled with the fact that $F=d(A\lrcorner \eta)$ implies that $dF=0$, will give us all of the source free Maxwell field equations. Secondly, you can check that a gauge transformation is given by $A\lrcorner\eta\mapsto A\lrcorner \eta+df$ for any function $f$. With this in mind, the inner the curvature tensor $F$ is gauge invariant as $F=d(A\lrcorner \eta+df)=F+ddf=F$. In non abelian gauge theories, this is not true, so $F$ itself is not gauge invariant, but the inner product is. This is the main reason why $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ pops up in the Lagrangian, because we want our Lagrangian to gauge invariant.

You can check in the case of electromagnetism that $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ is same as $\mathbf{E}^2-\mathbf{B}^2$. I personally don't know what this physically means, as my physical intuition for this stuff is poor.

If you want to look into this more, I recommend checking out $\textit{The Geometry of Physics}$ by Theodore Frankel.